# Mindscape Web Workbench Sass unknown mixin

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sass

I'm currently using Mindscape Web Workbench to create css from sass. I'm using an overall site.scss file that imports all other files.

```
  /*** Infrastructure ***************************************/
  /**********************************************************/
  @import "../../Infrastructure/_Common";
  @import "../../Layouts/Layout1/_Layout";

  /*** Theming **********************************************/
  /**********************************************************/
  @import "_Theme";
```

Mixins that I have defined in _Common are not known in _Theme. when site.css is compiled it all works fine but Mindscape Web Workbench's intelisense thinks the mixins are undefined. Is there a way for the plugin to know these mixins are defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SASS syntax of "@import" conflicts with .Net's syntax. When using SASS in .Net replace the "@import" with the keyword "@reference", and comment out the @reference (s). See http://getcassette.net/documentation/AssetReferences for more information.

Your code from above would be:

```
/*** Infrastructure ***************************************/
/**********************************************************/
/*
@reference "../../Infrastructure/_Common";
@reference "../../Layouts/Layout1/_Layout";
*/

/*** Theming **********************************************/
/**********************************************************/
/*
@reference "_Theme";
*/
```